# Bitcoin core or bitcoind as server on the network?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, wallet, network, server

does anyone know if it is possible to use a specific bitcoin kernel installation on a network as a server for the internal network so you do not have to install multiple complete bitcoin core copies on the stations?